# Change row dimensions on scrolling ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I have a `ListView` and my each row in the list is a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` and `TextView`. I want to change the dimensions of the `RelativeLayout` dynamically on scrolling of the list, such that the first and last row width is equal to screen width and the middle row width is half of the screen width. I am able to change the text size of the `TextView` dynamically using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    //Calculate height and width based on visible count items and position

    final int viewHeight = height // calculated based on row position;
    final int viewWidth = width //  calculated based on row position;

    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) {

        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(i);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        final TextView time = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.time);

        time.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               time.setTextSize(viewHeight);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

But I want to change the dimensions of the entire row layout dynamically on scrolling. Please check my code below. Any help appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    //Calculate height and width based on visible count items and position

    final int viewHeight = height // calculated based on row position;
    final int viewWidth = width //  calculated based on row position;

    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) {
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(i);
        setLayoutDimensions(layout,viewHeight, viewWidth);
    }
}

private void setLayoutDimensions(final RelativeLayout layout, final int height, final int width){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adaptLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    layout.setLayoutParams(adaptLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width and height of the relative layout like this:

```
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.width= width;
params.width= height;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you can convert your width and height to dp according to the device screen density using [TypedValue.applyDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)) method